# ViewController.swift and Cocoa Touch Class as a subclass of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am following an iOS Swift tutorial to build an app. The instructor suggested that I delete the ViewController.swift file and add a new Cocoa Touch Class template which would be a subclass of UIViewController but did not explain why. Can someone enlighten me on the reasoning behind this and its benefits oppose to building the app in the original ViewController.swift file?

Is it just a customization method to naming your files?

Comment: They may contain different boilerplate code, depending on your project type, or maybe the instructor just wanted to show you how to create a new Cocoa Touch subclass. Either way it doesn't really matter.

Comment: the initial viewController and one created after are the same (both inherit from UIViewController), that must have another aim

Comment: thanks alot guys. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The ViewController.swift file is created by default with the Single Application project template. An iOS project can have a lot ViewControllers.

> View controllers are the foundation of your app’s internal structure. Every app has at least one view controller, and most apps have several. Each view controller manages a portion of your app’s user interface as well as the interactions between that interface and the underlying data. View controllers also facilitate transitions between different parts of your user interface.

For more information you can check Apple documentation: [The Role of View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/)